# TreeView Drawing

Tags: winforms, gdi+

Is there a really quick and easy way to draw a TreeView in a GDI Graphics Object (its TreeNode Collection) in a way such as

[alt text http://www.tenstep.com.br/br/TenStepPGP/imagens/EAP5.jpg](http://www.tenstep.com.br/br/TenStepPGP/imagens/EAP5.jpg)

?

It could be a component do buy or any that is for free.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are be several ways to go about this:

- Write it yourself  (it's rather easy to do if you know the type of diagrams you're dealing with and customization is not important)
- Automate one of the well-known applications which do that (Visio or Omnigraffle come to mind).  In fact, when I had to programmatically generate manipulate diagrams like that, I ended up writing .NET code inside Visio.
- Look through open-source UML tools to see if there is code you can use.  A good list of such tools can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools#List_of_Non-commercial.2FFree_UML_tools).  Please pay attention to the license of the code you end up using.

Comment: I ended up using this component: http://mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html. It solved my issue. Anyways, thanks for the alternatives.